# How to perfect svg image of a happy face?

Tags: svg

I have created a sad image for 404 error redirect

```html
<svg width="134" height="134" viewBox="0 0 134 134" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#000" d="M1 67.388c.019 36.919 29.394 66.243 66.32 66.208 36.871-.035 66.285-29.472 66.272-66.322C133.58 30.515 103.994.979 67.208 1 30.383 1.021.981 30.503 1 67.388zm40.332 19.774c-.001-5.624 1.68-5.857 6.035-5.941 4.615-.091 5.879 1.391 5.885 5.941.005 4.635-1.426 5.956-5.988 5.954-4.646-.002-5.932-.632-5.932-5.954zm5.683-46.129c4.745 0 6.41.813 6.222 5.768-.159 4.2-.727 6.398-5.692 6.235-4.257-.139-6.411-.852-6.1-5.772.252-3.983 0-6.505 5.57-6.23zm42.203-7.042s3.979 3.479 5.616 5.05c-21.936 22.036-13.345 44.103-.445 57.111.001 0-2.744 3.34-4.633 4.948-17.013-11.334-24.77-47.625-.538-67.109z"/></svg>
```

Change some numbers from negative to positive

I managed to make the smile smile, but there are small imperfections, the circle is not well formed, the eyes and his smile.

```html
<svg width="134" height="134" viewBox="0 0 134 134" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
  M1 67.388
  c.019 36.919 29.394 66.243 66.32 66.208 
  c36.871-.035 66.285-29.472 66.272-66.322
  C133.58 30.515 103.99 4.979 67.208 1 
  C30.383 1.02 1.981 30.503 1 67.388z
  m40.332 19.774
  c-.001-5.624 1.68-5.857 6.035-5.941 
  c4.615-.091 5.879 1.391 5.885 5.94 
  c1.005 4.635 -1.426 5.956 -5.988 5.954
  c-4.646 -.002 -5.932-.632 -5.932-5.954z
  m5.683-46.129
  c4.745 0 6.4 1.813 6.222 5.768
  c-.159 4.2 -.727 6.398 -5.692 6.235
  c-4.257-.139 -6.411-.852 -6.1-5.77
  c2.252-3.983 0-6.505 5.57-6.23z
  m42.203-7.042
  s3.979 3.479 5.616 5.05
  c 21.936 22.036 13.345 44.103 .445 57.11
  c1.001 0 2.744 3.34 4.633 4.948
  c 17.013-11.334 24.77-47.625-.538-67.109z"/></svg>
```

How do I solve it correctly?

Comment: If you want a circle, then use a [`<circle>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just grab a royalty-free one from the web? eg. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Happy_face.svg